# How do android apps recognise phones

Tags: android

I downloaded an app and it has free trial period . When the it ended , I cleared the app data and subscribed again (with another email)  but the free trial period was already over.
so does the app recognize the phone in a way that even if I subscribe again I don't get free trial?! and how does it do that??

Comment: There are a lot of ways to determine if a certain phone already subscribe or installed an app. The developer can use the Device ID for example and records this ID in the server and so at this point they can able to check whether a device already have a record or not since the Device ID is unique per device.

Comment: refer this for getting unique device Id http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every android has unique device id. When you are install the app first time, the app will get your device id and forward it to server. So next time you will caught by android unique id.

Comment: @user7404947 You can't. It's coded inside the device's hardware.